# What 50's/60's TV or movie show featured a belt-mounted force-field?

Tags: story-identification

Back in the late 60's I watched a show or movie on TV. A guy had a little box on his belt that produced a force-field. I remember him demonstrating it by forcing another guy against a wall. For the guy with the force field it was effortless to pin and or crush the other guy if he wanted.

I don't remember if it was a TV serial or a movie. I've watched all of the old Twilight Zones, Outer Limits, and countless 1950's sci-fi flicks with no luck finding it yet.

Comment: I'm guessing this was live action, not a cartoon? Didn't the Dune film have this, are you thinking of that?

Comment: Dune was from the 80's. This show is black & white from the late 50's or 60's. It was a long time ago. I was pretty young when I saw it. It was scifi of some kind on network tv. The guys were wearing clothing from that period.

Comment: As I recall the force field was transparent but I remember the guy pinned was getting visibly pressed by the invisible field.

Comment: Yeah, it was filmed actors, not a cartoon.

Comment: See original question at http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=640831

Comment: No luck since your referenced post. I'm still searching. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I remember a scene like that in the Italian **Perry Rhodan** film [...4 ...3 ...2 ...1 ...morte](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0063859/), (1967), also known as **Mission Stardust**.  From the IMDB page's Goofs section:

> To accomplish the effect of an invisible forcefield being pressed
>   against a man, the FX dept used a pane of glass. Unfortunately, you
>   can see a reflection of the actor and a prop in his hands in it at
>   56:43 or so.

You can see the scene below:

Comment: This is probably the show....Thanks!! The scene at 18:30 isn't quite what I remember. But what I'm looking for is probably somewhere else in this movie. The DVD is on the way. I'll know for sure in a week or so. I'll provide an update soon.

Comment: Pretty sure now this is the scene I've been looking for. It's been so long since I saw it, it's easy to insert stuff that wasn't there. I doubt there is another show that duplicates this effect this closely. Thanks for the answer.